# Puppet exec log_output equivalent in Chef execute

Tags: chef-infra, puppet

In puppet, the exec resource has an attribute called log_output that can define when to log the output of the command (true, false or on_failure).

Does Chef have a similar directive or a common workaround to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of all commands gets logged when the log level is set to `DEBUG`. The easiest way to do this is on the command line for chef-solo and chef-client, `-l debug`.

Comment: Is there any attribute related way for this other than specifying log level at chef-client?

Comment: @Chamila Looks like there is no such option check the chef exec resource attributes http://docs.getchef.com/resource_execute.html

Comment: You can set the log level from inside your recipe if you want to be really fancy, but I wouldn't.